# How disconnect serial port

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I´m workin´ wiht a inteface on Qt, I have the conecction with a electronic board, and all is well, the problem is that I want to disconnect the serial port, but I can´t. I tryed this

```
electronic_board.clear();
```

and

```
if(electronic_board.isOpen())
   electronic_board.close();
```

but not worked.

The connectios is this

```
bool Init(){
Q_FOREACH(QSerialPortInfo port, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts()){
    electronic_board.setPortName(port.portName());
    electronic_board.setBaudRate(115200);
    electronic_board.setDataBits(QSerialPort::Data8);
    electronic_board.setParity(QSerialPort::NoParity);
    electronic_board.setStopBits(QSerialPort::OneStop);
    electronic_board.setFlowControl(QSerialPort::NoFlowControl);
    try {
        if(electronic_board.isOpen())
            electronic_board.close();
        if(electronic_board.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)){
            char arr[1] = {'O'};
            QByteArray Iniciar(arr,1);
                            electronic_board.write(Iniciar);
            electronic_board.waitForBytesWritten(500);
            QThread::msleep(30);
            electronic_board.waitForReadyRead(100);
                QByteArray requestData;
                int i = 0;
                while (requestData.length() != 1) {
                    QThread::msleep(10);
                    requestData = electronic_board.readAll();
                    if(i++ >= 30){
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(requestData[0] == 'K'){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (...) {

    }
}
return false;
```

}

The connections is correct, also use this

```
connect(&electronic_board,&QSerialPort::readyRead,this, frame_available);
```

So, How can I dissconnect the serial port??
Somebody can help me?

Comment: Please expand on the nature of the problem you are having. Serial ports are too simple to *connect* and *disconnect*. If no one's unplugged the wires, a serial port is always connected, and if it's unplugged there's often no way for the port to know. Usually the best you can do is open and close, and it looks like you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you use to close the serial port works, but you never call it for the last serial port of the list.